# DNX console app not picking up changes

Tags: c#, dnx

I'm running Visual Studio Code on OSX and am trying to get a console app running.

I have two projects, a class library and a console app. The console app's project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "classlibrary":""
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `classlibrary` is the namespace of the some of the classes I'm trying to use.

Inside the `classlibrary` namespace I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Foo {get;set;}
    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

In `Program.cs` intellisense is not picking up `MyClass` or `MyClass.Foo`. I'm running `dnu restore`, `dnu build` in both projects but I don't seem to be getting any further. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try mentioning version like `"classlibrary":"1.0.0-*"` and see if it works